# Debugging string reversal with java

Tags: java, string, recursion, reverse

I'm new to java, and I've been trying to produce code reversing a string using recursion. I've spent about a day thinking of solutions as to why it's not working as expected, to no avail. At this point in my debugging, the code compiles, but when executing, it produces a "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException" error. Can you tell me what's causing this?

```
class RevStr {
  String str,Final;

  RevStr(String string) {
    String str=string;
    String Final="";
  }

  void Reverse() {
    String str=str;
    int count=1;

    if(str.length()==1) {
      Final+=str;
    }
    else {
      String last=str.substring(str.length()-1);
      Final+=last;
      str=str.substring(0,(str.length()-1));
      Reverse();
    }
  }

  String RetRev() {
    return Final;
  }
}

class ReverseString {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    RevStr name=new RevStr("Cameron");
    name.Reverse();
    String rev=name.RetRev();
    //System.out.println(rev);
  }
}
```

Comment: What IDE do you use? IntelliJ has a nice debugger but any would do. Have you looked into **debuggubg** using a proper tool and not system.out?

Comment: I don't use an IDE, sticking to typing everything out in notepad.

Comment: in RevStr you're not actually assigning the class member #str to the parameter.

Comment: Error #1: "I don't use an IDE". Once you fix that error, life will be much simpler for you.

Comment: `String str=string;` **shadows** the field `str`. And thus `str` (the field) is `null`. Start by changing that to `this.str = string;`

Comment: `RevStr(String string) {
    String str=string;
    String Final="";
  }` you are declaring here *local variables* with name `str` and `Final`. Those are separate than fields with same name so those fields are still uninitialized. Also `String str=str;` shouldn't compile here so you would get different error than NPE.

Comment: lol @andreas if i could send u all my rep i would give it all to u for that comment. offtopic i know, sorry XD.

Comment: I had an answer, don't close this bad boy.

Comment: @Jason Is your answer better (more detailed, easier to understand, etc.) than answers provided in duplicate? If yes I can reopen it, but maybe instead consider posting your answer in duplicate question :)

Comment: Yeah u right :p

Comment: Thank you all, I finally got it (with your help)! I'll definitely invest in an IDE, and remember to use this. in these cases

Comment: @CamoTheSlav make sure the variable that holds the result isn't null at first too, initialize as "" (an empty String) or you will get nullnoremaC

Comment: *I'll definitely invest in an IDE* @CamoTheSlav IntelliJ Community Edition, Eclipse and NetBeans are all free. All you must invest is the time to learn the tool. And learning the tool will yield enormous immediate benefit.

Comment: @CamoTheSlav BlueJ is also free, easy to use, and has a debugger.

Comment: The key to making a recursive function is to divide the problem up so that each call to the function works on a smaller problem.